# Array of product ids for a given category (respecting is_anchor)

Tags: category, collection, product-collection, sql

I am trying to find the fastest way of getting a list/array of product id's for any given category id.

I understand this is quite fast `$category = new Varien_Object(array('id'=>$_cat));
$positions = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category')->getProductsPosition($category);`

but there must be a way of getting the individual id's in 1 go.

**So my question is:** how can I retrieve an array of productids from a category id?

(Ad. where the is_anchor attribute is respected - for this Magento this means that also underlying category products are added to the collection)

also read; http://www.blog.plazathemes.com/archives/2759

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only have the category ID and do not want to load the category itself, you can use this code (given category id `$categoryId`):

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setId($categoryId);
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addCategoryFilter($category)
    ->getAllIds();
```

This code respects the is_anchor attribute because the filter is using the index, so as a result it returns all products that Magento would show on front-end, including products from the underlying sub-categories.

Comment: @ShirtsofHolland thanks for the edit suggestion, I extended it with more information

Comment: thanks. However $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setId($categoryId)->setIsAnchor(false);
$includeIDs = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addCategoryFilter($category)->getAllIds(); doesnt show the collection without underlying products. We tried this many times - but it just doesnt give the expected result ....

Comment: OK I made a wrong assumption here. The anchor attribute is already respected in the category_product index and the index is used by this collection filter. I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_cat);
$prodCollection = $category->getProductCollection()->getAllIds();
```